# R: ggplot with durations

Tags: r, ggplot2, duration, lubridate

Question: Your advice for handling **durations** with `ggplot2` (author: Hadley Wickham). Specifically: reproduce the plots below with custom breaks and suitable labels. Preference for minimal use of custom functions and/or refactoring of data. Suggestions with packages I have not cited are welcome.

The data is stored in seconds (see `df` below). I would like to display human-eye readable breaks and labels, e.g. days instead of thousands of seconds, where the breaks occurs at 0, 1, 2... days instead of awkward fractions.

Proof of effort: The first example below deals with durations as integers and achieves the objective by appropriate case-by-case division by multiples of 60/24/365, etc. The second example uses the base `R` `difftime` objects. To get it right in this case, I had to use the `strptime` function and subtract `1`. Have I missed something? The third example uses the `duration` class from the `lubridate` package. While specifying labels was quite easy with the `day()` and `seconds_to_period()` functions, I didn't do such a good job at setting custom breaks. The fourth example uses the `hms` class. I managed to specify breaks, but not the labels. Any suggestions on how to write shorter lines of code for each of the examples below are also welcome.

```
# Data
df = data.frame(x = 1:6, 
    num = c(374400, 343500, 174000, 193500, 197700, 270300))

# base/difftime
df$difftime <- as.difftime(df$num, units = "secs")

# lubridate/duration
library("lubridate")  # devtools::install_github("tidyverse/lubridate") # the dev version fixes a bug
df$duration <- duration(df$num, units = "seconds")

# hms/hms
library("hms")
df$hms <- as.hms(df$num) 

library("ggplot2")
library("scales")

# 1: data is base/numeric
# Pro: no package dependence
# Con: Hard work 
breaks = seq(0, 100*60*60, 20*60*60)
labels = function(x) round(x/60/60/24, 0)
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = num)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "lightblue") +
    scale_y_continuous(name = "Duration (Days)", 
                       breaks = breaks,
                       labels = labels) +
    labs(title = "Data stored as numeric (seconds)", 
         subtitle = "breaks = seq(0, 100*60*60, 20*60*60)\nlabels = function(x) round(x/60/60/24, 0)",
         x = NULL) 
ggsave("base-num.png")
```

[image]

```
# 2: data is base/difftime
# Pro: simple once you get over the ``strftime(x, "%d")`` syntax.
# Unresolved: Why do I need to subtract a day?
labels = function(x) as.integer(strftime(x, "%d"))-1
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = difftime)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "lightblue") +
    scale_y_time(name = "Duration (Days)", 
        labels = labels) +
    labs(title = "Data stored as difftime (seconds)", 
         subtitle = "default breaks\nlabels = function(x) as.integer(strftime(x, '%d'))-1",
         x = NULL) 
ggsave("base-difftime.png")
```

[image]

```
# 3: data is lubridate/duration
# Pro: intuitive combination of day() and seconds_to_period() functions
# Unresolved: a better way to make own breaks?
breaks = as.duration(seq(0, 5, 1)*60*60*24)
labels = function(x) day(seconds_to_period(x))
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = duration)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "lightblue") +
    scale_y_continuous(name = "Duration (Days)", 
        breaks = breaks,
        labels = labels) +
    labs(title = "Data stored as duration (seconds)", 
         subtitle = "breaks = as.duration(seq(0, 5, 1)*60*60*24)\nlabels = function(x)lubridate::day(lubridate::seconds_to_period(x))",
         x = NULL) 
ggsave("lubridate-duration.png")
```

[image]

```
# 4: data is hms/hms
# Pro: Immediately generates plot with acceptable labels
# Unresolved: how to make own labels:  Failed attempts:
labels = 0:(length(breaks)-1)
labels = function(x)lubridate::day(x)

breaks = seq(0, 5, 1)*60*60*24
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = hms)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "lightblue") +
    scale_y_continuous(name = "Duration (Seconds)",
        breaks = breaks) +
    labs(title = "Data stored as hms (seconds)", 
         subtitle = "breaks = seq(0, 5, 1)*60*60*24\ndefault labels",
         x = NULL) 
ggsave("hms-hms.png")
```

[image]

**EDIT** Following Axeman's suggestion in the comments section, this is how to combine `ggplot` with `hms` objects. This looks to me like the most convenient of the 4, though admittedly having to subtract `1` is unexpected. Axeman, do you want to post this as an answer?

```
breaks = hms::hms(days = 0:4)
labels = function(x) lubridate::day(x)-1
```

[image]

Comment: Using `hms` you can do `scale_y_time(
    name = "Duration (days)", 
    breaks = hms::hms(days = 0:4),
    labels = function(x) lubridate::day(x) - 1
  )`. Still need to subtract 1 for some reason though.. Not sure why. Time support is kind of limited compared date support.

Comment: That's a great step forward, thanks Axeman! :-)

Comment: @Axeman, see my edit above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO, the proposed solutions look overly complicated to me.

If durations are given as integer seconds and need to be plotted on a day scale, my approach is to scale it in the call to `aes()`:

```
df = data.frame(x = 1:6, 
                num = c(374400, 343500, 174000, 193500, 197700, 270300))
library("ggplot2")
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = num / (24*60*60))) +
  geom_col(fill = "lightblue") +
  labs(title = "Data stored as numeric (seconds)",
       y = "Duration (Days)",
       x = NULL)
```

[image]

So, no need to fiddle about breaks and labels.

N.B.: `geom_col()` is a replacement for  `geom_bar(stat = "identity")`.